# What does the ## represent when it is used as a function argument in e.g. Manipulate?

Tags: functions

what does the `##` represent in following expression:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x],{x,0,4Pi}],
   {{a,1},0,4,AngularGauge[##,ImageSize->125]&},ControlPlacement->Left]
```

[image]

In this case, what is the arguments list the `##` represent? Does `##` represent the arguments list of `Manipulate` function and what is it? I understant when it is used in this case: `f[##]&[a,b,c,d]`.

Comment: `##` means `SlotSequence`. If you go to Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation and type there `##` you get detailed information.

Comment: It represents the list of arguments `Manipulate` passes on to the controller, which, in this case is defined as a custom `AngularGauge` function. This list of arguments is explained under the documentation of `Manipulate` > Details & Options: "The form `{u, u_min, u_max, func}` can also be used; what is evaluated is then `func[Dynamic[u],{u_min, u_max}]`."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/12 in particular.